# how to make each element in an array another array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Hi I came across a problem. I have a numpy array with size (256, 144). Each element is 0 in this array. Now I want to make each element in the array to be [0, 0, 0]. Is there a way of doing this?

The code is:

```
empty_windows = np.zeros(256, 144)
for i in range(256*144):
    empty_windows[i] = [0,0,0]
```

This method doesnt work as it returns an error message "ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence."

Is there a way of doing this? Thank you very much.

Comment: `empty_windows` as created holds a float in each of the 256*144 cells.  You can't put a 3 element list in a slot meant for one float!.  But if you start with a (256,144,3) shape, you can assign  `empty_windows[i,j,:] = [1,2,3]`.  By the way `np.zeros(256,144)` is wrong.  It should be `np.zeros((256,144))`.  I think you need to read some more numpy basics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't need to do anything with `empty_windows` while it has size (256, 144), you can simply create it with the proper size:

```
empty_windows = np.zeros((256, 144, 3))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try creating a second numpy array with the required shape, which in your case is `(256,144,3)` , iterating over it and correcting the elements as required.

```
empty_windows = np.zeros((256, 144))

x = np.random.rand(256,144,3)

for i in range(256):
  for j in range(144):
    x[i][j] = [empty_windows[i][j] for _ in range(3)]

empty_windows = x
```

You may also want to brush up on your understanding of numpy arrays, as the commenter mentioned, particularly how to initialize and iterate over them.